# Set UIButton text

Tags: objective-c, xcode, text, uibutton, uilabel

It is my text label:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textEmail;


 _titleGet = [_dictionaryGeter objectForKey:@"Email"];
    _textEmail.text= _titleGet;
```

objectForKey:@"Email" from plist

I want to make button. How to make that button title to be equal to the textEmail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to set the title of a `UIButton`.

Option 1 (the wrong way):
`myButton.titleLabel.text = myString`

Option 2 (the right way):
`[myButton setTitle:myString forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

So, your code would be:

```
_titleGet = [_dictionaryGeter objectForKey:@"Email"];
[_btn setTitle:_titleGet forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: `NSString *sendEmail = [_dictionaryGeter objectForKey:@"Number"];
    [_btn setTitle:sendEmail forState:UIControlStateNormal];` ????

Comment: I added an example to help clarify.

Comment: I did it .but button title not changed

Comment: When you log out the string before setting the button title, what was printed? Then, when you set the button title for `UIControlStateNormal`, what is both the button state and the title (both of those can be logged)?

Answer (score 0):

To change a buttons text is pretty much the same

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonEmail;


_titleGet = [_dictionaryGeter objectForKey:@"Email"];
_textEmail.text= _titleGet;

buttonEmail.text =  _titleGet;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is great just a small bug i found:
Just change

```
_textEmail.text= _titleGet;
```

to

```
_textEmail.titleLabel.text= _titleGet;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
_titleGet = [_dictionaryGeter objectForKey:@"Email"];

 NSString *valueToSave = _titleGet
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"keyYourChoice"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


NSString *xyx = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
stringForKey:@"keyYourChoice"];

 _textEmail.text= xyx;
```

THANK YOU