# Button title is cropped. Why?

Tags: swift3

I have button and Picker View. If i'm trying to choose item in Picker View and use text for Button's tittle it have cropped text. Why?

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource
{

let array = ["Incredible", "Fantastic"]

@IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
{
    return array.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
{
    button.setTitle(array[row], for: .normal)
    return array[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat
{
    return 50
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}
}
```

Screenshots of Device emulator & XCODE's Storyboard:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing whatever that control is, you need to make it wider.

Comment: No, the width of the button is sufficient

Comment: Try using button.setTitle as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35679624/5612720

Comment: I just add this: button.setTitle(array[row], for: .normal) and it works fine! Thanks!